# Saving csv file in PHP to see polish characters in excel

Tags: php, excel, file, encoding

Here's my code

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('ą', 'ó', 'ż', 'ź'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

It kinda works but when I open the file in excel I see completely different characters:

```
"Ä…", "Ăł", "ĹĽ" , "Ĺş"
```

How can I encode a proper, excel-readable characters?

Answer (score 0):

add Byte Order mark (BOM) for UTF-8 before `fputs`, it will writes file header for correct encoding

```
fprintf($fp, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
```

after

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
```